# Differentiating login signposting for business and non business users

Tags: gui-design, registration, b2b

I'm building a social media endorsement platform that needs involvement from both business and non-business users. We've had some problems with the registration process on the business user side, mainly due to signposting and having more than one focal point for signing up/signing in. I'm currently simplifying this and settling for a sign in link for business users and another for non-business users/visitors/consumers (the crux of my issue) but I can't decide how to label these 2 buttons to make it clear which you should select when you arrive at the site.

Currently I have this:

- Visitor login
- Business login

My question is, if you were browsing a website as a business and saw these 2 links, would it be obvious which one you should select? How could I better label them to make it obvious which link should be selected?

I've also toyed with these combinations:

- Sign up/in and Brand sign up/in
- User login and Business login
- Consumer login and Business login

Finally, should I instead replace the 2 buttons with a single button and signpost business/consumer users from the sign in page? My business partner is not keen on this approach but I don't like the labelling of, and can't find a suitable solution to, the non-business user sign in button text.

Answer (score 1):

What is the difference between business and non business users?

Take the example of a careers site. The "Consumer" login is for those wishing to find a new job - i.e. "Candidates". The "Business" login is for those with a job to fill - i.e. "Employers". This distinction give you the labels for your different login options.

Another example would be an small ads site. Those posting ads would be "Advertisers", those looking at ads for things to buy would be "Users" or "Customers".

Think about your business and what each sector is doing on your site. Then the label for the different logins might become clear.

Comment: Well, in this case, business users are those who post offers for redemption and consumer users are those who browse and redeem those offers. Nothing stands out by way of a label for the consumers that they would implicitly recognise as describing them.

Answer (score 1):

I think you could use single <kbd>Sign Up</kbd> button on a Home page which leads to descriptive Sign Up page. The reasons are:

1. Home page have small space to contain description for the options. So the options could be confusing for a user.
2. User cannot make error clicking on a wrong button.
3. Special Sign Up page contains description, which allows user to choose right way.

[image]

Comment: This is the approach I'm favouring at the moment. There is some extra content I would like to provide to the users as they are signing up that explains the end-to-end sign up process in easily consumable form, so having a single page for all of this (and a single route to get there) seems to makes sense.

Comment: Better than original, but still a not-so-good approach. Why: visitor will see two options on sign-up page (1), on login page (2) on any page with read-only information for a certain type of user (3+). That's at least 3 pages where visitor has to choose his type and will see information meant for the other type. The best way will be to firstly prompt 1 single time what type he is, and after that show only appropriate forms/information on all pages.

Comment: @Alph.Dev (1) options have descriptions, (2) login page doesn't need differentiate users, it's role-based approach. The server does it, (3) unregistered user has no access to resources. Though, it's only my assumptions, so you could be right.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way is to have one login form for all users. If the user is a business, take them to the business area. If they are a visitor, take them to the visitors area. It seems like users will rarely be both businesses and visitors -- but if they are, you can just ask them when they sign in whether they want to be taken to the visitor or business section of the website.

Alternatively, you could take the user to the section they use most often (their primary context) and allow them to easily switch to a visitor or business context.

Answer (score 0):

Why should each visitor even see 2 different login/signup options? Seeing things you are not supposed to see is an usability flaw.

Determine/ask them what type of visitor they are **at an earlier stage**. And remember it in a session or URL. And then display only 1 appropriate login/signup option.